# Imported object is undefined.

Tags: javascript, import, ecmascript-6

In the below code, in the `uploadEditImageEpic`, `s3options` is undefined. Why is that? It is just an import from a file that exports an object.

components/addPage/epic.js

```
import type { S3Options } from '../../types/image'

export const s3options: S3Options = {
  keyPrefix: 'xxxx',
  bucket: 'xxx',
  region: 'xxx',
  accessKey: 'xxx',
  secretKey: 'xxx',
  successActionStatus: xxx
}
```

components/editProduct/epic.js

```
import { s3options } from '../addPage/epic'

export const uploadEditImageEpic: Epic<*, *, *> = (
  action$: ActionsObservable<*>
) =>
  action$.ofType(UPLOAD_EDIT_IMAGE).mergeMap(action => {
    return Observable.fromPromise(RNS3.put(action.payload, s3options))
      .map((response: AjaxResponse) => uploadEditImageFulfilled(response))
      .catch((error: AjaxResponse) => {
        return Observable.of(uploadEditImageRejected(error))
      })
  })
```

types/image.js

```
export type S3Options = {
  [x: string]: any,
  keyPrefix: string,
  bucket: string,
  region: string,
  accessKey: string,
  secretKey: string,
  successActionStatus: number
}
```